# mikeal request bad formatted body

Tags: html, node.js, zip, request

i'm using mikeal/request. I have a problems with some webpage when i use:

```
var url='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbP1K-bQB6g&list=SP018BE450221B431B';
var request = require('request');
request(url, function (error, response, body) {      
    console.log(body);      
})
```

this print the body well-formatted in html. Sometimes with different urls it prints something like:

```
ÿÿ´Wmo7þ|ú¦{@ã »ZÉ9ŸãÄ2 ØªOl+¶Ü4W½K­èì’[’+K.úé~ ecc...
```

but when i navigate it trought the browser i can see the page clearly.
Any suggestion? I already tried to decode it with StringDecoder but nothing... i'm using this url to get the error:

```
http://www.agi.it/estero/notizie/201210250805-est-rt10017-performance_stellari_e_10_ore_autonomia_e_gia_ipad_mini_mania
```

Answer (score 2):

The response is gzipped, it seems. If you can't get the server to honor your request headers, you'll need to decode the response.

**EDIT**:
You can explicitly set the request headers like this:

```
request({ url: <your url>, headers: { 'accept-encoding': 'identity' }}, function (error, reponse, body) {
  // You really should receive an un-encoded body, now
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'm trying to use zlib in nodejs: in the example they always put the result in a stream of something. I need to decode the response and get the body and then use it. if i try           response.pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(result); with result as a variable; i get this error stream.js:52  dest.on('drain', ondrain); TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined

Comment: The server shouldn't be sending you a gzipped response if your request doesn't indicate that you accept it. So, you should report a bug to the admin of that server. But more importantly, you can set an explicit request header that indicates that you cannot handle gzipped response.